# Clicking on a div shows a button but hides buttons on other divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to make a note-keeping app in which there are many divs as notes and I want that whenever the user clicks on a particular div then it should be made editable and a button shows on top of div which before the action was hidden. I have somewhat done this part. Now I want that when the user clicks on other div or other parts of the page, then the already shown button goes hidden.
In short, those div's button should be visible where the user is currently working.

I am not sure how to just make the one button visible at a time.

the javascript I used for the button shown is:

```
edits=document.getElementsByClassName('new');
        Array.from(edits).forEach((element) => {
        child=element.childNode
            element.addEventListener("click",(e)=>
            {
                let data=e.target;
                data.contentEditable=true;
                let btn=data.getElementsByTagName('button');
                Array.from(btn).forEach(element => {
                    console.log(element);
                    element.style.display="block";
                    element.contentEditable=false;  
                });
            });
        });
```

here is that part of code
https://jsfiddle.net/mahajaved/sq7zuakf/

Comment: As you tag jQuery, here like this you can do with jQuery $('body').on('click','.new',function(){
   var self=$(this);
   $(".update").hide();
   self.find(".update").show();
});

Comment: Satinder Singh Thank you so much it works

Comment: Satinder singh If I want to enable this function on clicking on other part of page then how to do this?